# playOrm - Initial test file run - TestManyToOne.java

Tags: java, eclipse, playorm

Getting started with the test file - TestManyToOne.java, I thought I would just run the file in Eclipse, to see what happens, or what I should expect??? In doing so, I get a slurry of information within the console,...

see information below,

...as well as a couple **Java Exception Breakpoints.**

- Is that something to be concerned with?
- In the realm of debugging, *where will I want to place my line breakpoints?*

Thanks ahead of time, for the insight, 
Ryan

**Console info is extensive, so only posting last few line; If more information is necessary, please advise...**

```
    `CF=DboColumnMeta persist rowkey=PartSecurity:id
     CF=DboTableMeta persist rowkey=PartSecurity
    `CF=DboColumnMeta persist rowkey=PartSecurity:id
     CF=DboColumnMeta persist rowkey=StringIndice:id
    `CF=DboColumnMeta persist rowkey=PartSecurity:id
     CF=DboTableMeta persist rowkey=StringIndice
    `CF=DboColumnMeta persist rowkey=PartSecurity:id
     CF=DboColumnMeta persist rowkey=DecimalIndice:id
    `CF=DboColumnMeta persist rowkey=PartSecurity:id
     CF=DboTableMeta persist rowkey=DecimalIndice
    `CF=DboColumnMeta persist rowkey=PartSecurity:id
     CF=DboColumnMeta persist rowkey=IntegerIndice:id
    `CF=DboColumnMeta persist rowkey=PartSecurity:id
     CF=DboTableMeta persist rowkey=IntegerIndice
    `CF=DboColumnMeta persist rowkey=PartSecurity:id
     CF=DboDatabaseMeta persist rowkey=nosqlorm
    `CF=DboColumnMeta persist rowkey=PartSecurity:id
     2012-09-12 09:52:06,830         `CF=DboColumnMeta persist rowkey=PartSecurity:id
     com.alvazan.orm.layer9z.spi.db.inmemory.InMemorySession
    `CF=DboColumnMeta persist rowkey=PartSecurity:id
     `CF=DboColumnMeta persist rowkey=PartSecurity:id
     `CF=DboColumnMeta         `CF=DboColumnMeta persist rowkey=PartSecurity:id
     persist rowkey=PartSecurity:id
     lookupColFamily
    INFO: CREATING column family=DboColumnMeta in the in memory nosql store
    2012-09-12 09:52:06,830         `CF=DboColumnMeta persist rowkey=PartSecurity:id
     com.alvazan.orm.layer9z.spi.db.inmemory.InMemorySession          lookupColFamily
    `CF=DboColumnMeta persist rowkey=PartSecurity:id
    `CF=DboColumnMeta persist rowkey=PartSecurity:id
     INFO: CREATING column family=DboTableMeta in the in memory nosql store
    `CF=DboColumnMeta persist rowkey=PartSecurity:id
     2012-09-12 09:52:06,850         `CF=DboColumnMeta persist rowkey=PartSecurity:id
     com.alvazan.orm.layer9z.spi.db.inmemory.InMemorySession                 `CF=DboColumnMeta persist rowkey=PartSecurity:id
     `CF=DboColumnMeta         `CF=DboColumnMeta persist rowkey=PartSecurity:id
     persist rowkey=PartSecurity:id
     lookupColFamily
    `CF=DboColumnMeta persist rowkey=PartSecurity:id
     INFO: CREATING column family=DboDatabaseMeta in the in memory nosql store
    `CF=DboColumnMeta persist rowkey=PartSecurity:id
     2012-09-12 09:52:06,851 com.alvazan.orm.logging.NoSqlRawLogger sendChanges
    INFO: [rawlogger] Sending Changes to server took(including spi plugin)=21 ms`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in TestManyToOne.java, a good breakpoint would be in the simple testReadWrite method or line 79 in this version

https://github.com/deanhiller/playorm/blob/6f5ed41d2d284902c194b843ac90876da55bab0b/input/javasrc/com/alvazan/test/TestManyToOne.java

Then you could step into readWriteBasic method.  I am not sure what you mean by "A couple of java exception breakpoints"?  perhaps a screenshot of what you mean there?

Also, your console implies you may be running EVERY test in a class or the whole test suite.  I would instead just right click the method you want to run/debug "testReadWrite" and run/debug just that one method(you won't have as much in the console that way either).

Dean